# Writing ISO file to USB

Tags: dd, iso, bootable, usb-device

I need to write a windows7 iso file on my usb stick.
I had been used to this task. I usually either use the `dd` tool, or `unetbootin`. Surprisingly both don't work today.

With `dd` I did the following :

```
dd bs=4m if='windows7.iso' of=/dev/sdb
```

My new supposedly bootable usb stick wont boot. Ok so I used `unetbootin`. This time, I get the `unetbootin` bootloader screen, but windows7 is not listed. Only the default choice is left.

In either way, I failed at creating my bootable stick. Few months ago, I could make this same USB stick boot with the very same ISO file. I also did the same tasks after formatting my stick withh this command:

```
mkfs.vfat -F 32 -I /dev/sdb
```

There were no difference as expected.

I am probably doing something wrong here, but I can't see where my mistake is.

Any idea on what is going on?

Comment: You can try `cat` or `pv windows7.iso > /dev/sdb` then `sync`. Always works for me.

Comment: I don't know if it matters in this case, but one thing you are doing wrong is running `mkfs` on the whole disk, instead of a partition.  USB sticks, like hard disks, usually need to be partitioned and then you put a filesystem in the partition.

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider trying it one more time, possibly with a fresh memory stick, including a "sync" prior to yanking it out  (and are we sure that dd is case insensitive for the megabyte suffix?  i use 'M' not 'm')

```
dd bs=4M if=windows7.iso of=/dev/sdb && sync
```

Plus the usual tedious suggestion about trying a different iso file (perhaps a linux one? ;) to test that your "windows7.iso isn't starting out corrupt (somehow)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes most likely have to get a new version of my iso. It works wth all my other iso files except for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that this is the very same ISO you've used in the past? As far as I'm aware, Windows 7 ISOs are usually not hybrid images that can be `dd`'d to a USB stick like those available for many Linux distros, though Microsoft does provide a [tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) for downloading an image that can be burned to USB, which is probably the easiest method (if you have a Windows machine available to run the downloader).

If that's not an option, you may be interested in this [slightly hacky](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162174/how-do-i-use-unetbootin-to-make-a-bootable-windows-usb-installer) way to trick `unetbootin` into creating a working bootable flash drive for Windows. It's been a few years since I've needed to do this, but your issue might be solved by making it write to an NTFS-formatted drive. (Remember to set the boot flag when partitioning.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but without success. It works with other iso files which means the one I need is probably corrupted.